"Node_Label" in the Neo4jVector couldn't be modified
I am trying to initialize the vector store from the existing graph to perform  for vector similarity search. But whatever the value assigned for the "node_label" property wasn't considered.
In the below code example, I assign the "Codeexample" value to the "node_label". However, after the vector store initialization I printed the value of "node_label" and it simply return "Document" every time.  This makes my vector similarity search to return empty results.
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Neo4jVector

driver = GraphDatabase.driver(url, auth=(username, password))

//Initialize LangChain components
embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vector_store = Neo4jVector.from_existing_graph(
    embedding=embedding,    
    url=url,
    username=username,
    password=password,
    node_label="Codeexample",
    text_node_properties=["id", "name", "description", "code"],
    embedding_node_property="embedding",
)

//Print Debug Information
print("Node Label:", vector_store.node_label)
----- Node Label: Document ------

//Process natural language query
query = "My code example query"
query_embedding = embedding.embed_query(query)

//Search in the knowledge graph
results = vector_store.similarity_search(query, k=1)
results

Please check this and let me know if I am missing anything here. Thanks in advance :)
